# How do I import csv files into a ms sql database?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server-2008, csv

I'm really out of my league here, but I hear that it can be done.

I have a PBX phone server with raw phone data in thousands of different CSV files that are captured every so often (between 8 minutes and 2 hours) that are stored in dated folders.

The only way I can connect to the server is through WinSCP, which just gives me the file structure (looks like Filezilla FTP).

So 2 things:

1. How would someone go about importing thousands of files into a SQL Server database (2008)?
2. How would someone go about setting up a timed event to import new CSV files as they are created?

I just need some direction. I don't even know where to start.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not a bad question, but it doesn't have much to do with Python.  Also, this seems like a better fit for [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: are you specifically looking for python solution?

Comment: @Vikram I'm not specifically, but I did hear it was possible from a person who used a Python script to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the permissions, you can do a `BULK INSERT` using `sqlcmd` with a batch file. In addition, you can create an SSIS package.

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

1- There are many ways to load csv files into sql server i.e  BCP ,BulkLoad, OpenRowSet( Bulk provider) ,SSIS ,Your Custom .Net application

Most popular is Bulk insert. See this blog for tutorial

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

2- Timed event ? again many options but most straight forward -> Setup Nighly SQL jobs

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

namespace ReadDataFromCSVFile
  {
    static class Program
      {
        static void Main()
        {
            string csv_file_path=@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.csv";
            DataTable csvData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);
            Console.WriteLine("Rows count:" + csvData.Rows.Count);            
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
        {
            DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
            try
            {
              using(TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
                 {
                    csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                    csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                    string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
                    foreach (string column in colFields)
                    {
                        DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                        datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                        csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
                    }
                    while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                    {
                        string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                        //Making empty value as null
                        for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (fieldData[i] == "")
                            {
                                fieldData[i] = null;
                            }
                        }
                        csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return csvData;
        }
      }
    }
```